# The table ALL_CONS_OBJ_COLUMNS table does not have data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to obtain data from de data dictionary that Oracle provides to its databases. When I execute the query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

I get the names from the tables I own as user and the tables other users have granted me access to (Around 130). Now, when I try to execute

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_CONS_OBJ_COLUMNS;
```

I get nothing, the result is an empty table. Does that make sense? As the docs says "*displays information about the types that object columns (or attributes) or collection elements have been constrained to, in the tables accessible to the current user*.", I think it should display the same table the previous query did.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong: I'm looking for ALL_CONS_COLUMNS. That table does not have all the names of the preiovus one, but has the ones I need. I guess I not fully understand the notion of objects yet.